# how to load comments while calling through ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Actually i am sending the name and comment to insert into the database and displaying to the particular div and this is displaying twice in div, how to overcome this, this is my code

```
  $("#main").load("insert.php",{comments:comments,name:name,email:email},function(){
  $("#display").append($("#main").html())
            });
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="comment_box">
Name : <input type="text" id="name"/> <br/>
Email : <input type="email" id="email"/> <br/>
<textarea cols=50 rows=10 id="input_text" placeholder="Discuss here"></textarea><br/>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

this is code while i am loading ajax, sending the id values and loading in a particular div and which div i have to put hidden i am not able to get.
please help how to create comments in doing with ajax.

Comment: Is `#main` set to `display:none` in your CSS?

Comment: This: `$("#main").load("insert.php",{comments:comments,name:name,email:email});` alone will execute insert.php and take what gets returned an put it in `#main`. Where do you want the output from insert.php to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to empty the `#main` element after you copy its contents to `#display`:

```
$("#main").load("insert.php",{comments:comments,name:name,email:email},function(){
    $("#display").append($("#main").html());
    $("#main").empty();
});
```